# How do you do an insertion sort in assembly?

Tags: assembly, masm, irvine32

I have been working on a program for insertion sort, but I can't seem to get it to work. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong? Just ignore the `enterArray` procedure, I'm just trying to figure out the algorithm right now.

```
TITLE Insertion Sort (main.asm)
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc

.data
myArray  SDWORD 12, 9, 15, 5
str1 byte "Enter the array: " ,0
str2 byte "The sorted array is: ",0

.code
main PROC
    call Clrscr
    ;call enterArray
    call InsertionSort
    exit
main ENDP


enterArray PROC
;reads the array from the console
    pushad
    mov edi, OFFSET myArray
    mov edx, OFFSET str1
    call WriteString
    call ReadInt
    mov [edi], eax
    add edi, 4
    popad
    ret
enterArray ENDP

InsertionSort PROC
    pushad

    mov ecx, SIZEOF myArray -1
    mov eax, OFFSET myArray

    outterloop:
    mov edx,myArray[eax]
    mov ebx,eax

    beginwhile:
        cmp ebx,0
        JE endwhile
        cmp myArray[ebx-4],edx
        JNG endwhile
        mov edx,myArray[ebx]
        mov myArray[ebx-4],edx
        sub edx,4
        JMP beginwhile
    endwhile:
    add eax,4
    LOOP outterloop

    popad
    ret
InsertionSort ENDP

END main
```

Comment: `mov ebx,eax

beginwhile:
    cmp ebx,0` Why are you moving `eax` into `ebx`? Why not just stick with the one `eax`?

Answer (score 1):

```
mov edx,myArray[ebx]
mov myArray[ebx-4],edx
sub edx,4
```

You should be swapping the elements but instead you are overwriting `myArray[ebx-4]` without making a temporary copy to replace `myArray[ebx]` with.

Also your register copy of the current element `myArray[ebx]`, `edx` should not be altered in the following line.

```
sub edx,4
```

Hope these two bugs allow you to get your solution working. I don't know enough to re-write the whole thing for you. I don't have privileges to reformat your post's code so please hit my up arrow if this has helped.